# Playstation Store wishlist notification when game goes on sale

Tags: ps4, psn

I have a Playstation Store wishlist and I'm wondering if I can get notification when the games/add-ons/DLC's that are on that wishlist go on sale.

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly such a feature isn't available but there are several web sites and mobile apps that can do that.

A few websites:

https://psdeals.net/

https://psprices.com/

I personally use the app from PSDeals and it works quite well: https://www.psdealsapp.com/

Comment: Thanks a lot, too bad the app is only for iOS

Comment: @Jungkook You can always use the site (psdeals.net) to set up notifications. The developer of the psdeals app said that they will be releasing the android counterpart pretty soon. There's already a beta available but you have to install it manually so I rather not link it on here but you can google it.

Comment: For PSDeals I need a subscription? And PSPrices doesn't seem to load.

Comment: @Jungkook Apologies, I had the wrong url for PSPrices. I have corrected it now (apparently www is not a thing any more)

Comment: That one is free?

Comment: @Jungkook AFAIK both are free, I only used the app for psdeals which is free. You'll have to sign up to find out but you can also google for PS4 price notifications and you'll get a ton of sites that do this. These 2 are the most popular.

Comment: PS Deals Premium
Get access to all premium features with one subscription on all your devices
And I can choose for monthly, 3 monthly or lifetime subscription

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91974/discussion-between-xander-and-jungkook).